# How to implement a custom container in CQ5

Tags: aem

I need to implement a container in CQ5, which contains markup and i need to be able to drag and drop components into the container via "sitekick. How can a implement such a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to look into the parsys and take it from there. You could extend it ad create a custom HTML that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Those "container"s are called "Components" in CQ5.

I recommend starting with their documentation.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/getting_started/first_steps_for_developers.html

You can start with extending existing components, or once you feel comfortable with all the pieces (what is required to list in the sidekick, dialogs, the markup, etc), you can build your own from scratch.

Hint: they include examples under the /lib/* path - but you have to implement your own under /apps/* - and following conventions will help you.

In localhost CRX-DE, you can examine:

- [System list] /libs/foundation/components/list
- [Example extended List] /apps/geometrixx/components/list